# Test-Netconneciton using Invoke command

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to invoke test-Net connection command from laptop for more than 1000 servers. I am using below code for execution. However the result it showing is always TRUE which is not correct , if I ran individual command the several result is FALSE as well.

```
Test-NetConnection $args[1] -InformationLevel Quiet
```

```
$MyObjectArray = Import-Csv ".\Sources.csv"

#################################################################
# Define a new empty Array which will be used to print the data #   
#################################################################
 
$AllObjects = @()

#################################################################
# Run a for loop to read ,and execute command for every row     #   
#################################################################

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $MyObjectArray.count ; $i++)
{
$SourceServer= $MyObjectArray[$i].Source
$HostServer = $MyObjectArray[$i].Host 
$PortNumber = $MyObjectArray[$i].Port

#############################################################################################
# Change and modify the $args and $result variable to add/upate/remove command execution    #   
#############################################################################################

#$args = "-computer " + $HostServer + " -Port " + $PortNumber #+ " -InformationLevel Quiet"

$args = "Test-NetConnection " + $HostServer + " -Port " + $PortNumber #+ " -InformationLevel Quiet"
#$result = Invoke-Command -FilePath .\myTNC.ps1 -ArgumentList $args -ComputerName $SourceServer

#################################################################
# Define Field name which you need to print in CSV file         #   
#################################################################

 $AllObjects += [pscustomobject]@{
 #$result =Invoke-command -ComputerName $SourceServer -ScriptBlock {Test-NetConnection $args -InformationLevel detailed}
  $result = Invoke-Command -FilePath .\myTNC.ps1 -ArgumentList $args -ComputerName $SourceServer 
# Invoke-command -ComputerName INDELVR1077 -ScriptBlock {Test-NetConnection INDELVS200 -Port 49667 -InformationLevel Quiet}
       Source = $SourceServer
       Host = $HostServer
       Port = $PortNumber
       Status =$result

}}$AllObjects | Export-Csv -Path ".\TestResult.csv" -NoTypeInformation #Store in CSV file
```

```
Expected output:
Source, Dest, Port, Result
AAA,BBB,8080,TRUE
AAA,CCC, 5678, TRUE
BBB,AAA.7878,FALSE
```

Comment: What is `myTNC.ps1`?

Comment: it's just a file with TNS command which is being called every time based on FOR loop content as 
Test-NetConnection $args[1] -InformationLevel Quiet

Answer (score 1):

$args is reserved and won't work. I usually make it $myargs.  It doesn't look like strictmode catches it.

```
$args = 'hi'
$args

# nothing


$myargs = 'hi'
$myargs

hi
```

Comment: $args is working fine at least for me , because it is running the command , the concern is it's not giving the correct result while running in loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Store the CSV data in temporary Array
$MyObjectArray = Import-Csv ".\Sources.csv"

# Define a new empty Array which will be used to print the data
$AllObjects = @()

# Run a for loop to read and execute command for every row
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $MyObjectArray.count ; $i++) { $SourceServer= $MyObjectArray[$i].Source $HostServer = $MyObjectArray[$i].Host $PortNumber = $MyObjectArray[$i].Port

# Change and modify the $args and $result variable to add/update/remove command execution
# All commands should be passed as variable
# $args = " Test-NetConnection " + $HostServer + " -Port " + $PortNumber + " -InformationLevel Quiet"

$InvokeCommand = "Invoke-Command "+ "-ComputerName "+ $SourceServer

$Expression= $InvokeCommand + " -Scriptblock { "+ $args +" } "

$Result = Invoke-Expression $Expression

# Define Field name which you need to print in CSV file

$AllObjects += [pscustomobject]@{ Source = $SourceServer Host = $HostServer Port = $PortNumber Status =$Result

}}$AllObjects | Export-Csv -Path ".\Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation #Store in CSV file
```

Comment: This would be much more useful if you explained why it answers the question and it was formatted neatly.  Please also read the [help] pages about [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer.